# Why CouldNotLockPageException occured on production server but not on local system?

Tags: java, spring, apache2, wicket, tomcat9

We are facing CouldNotLockPageException If this exception occurred on our production environment, we to have restart the tomcat.
When I tried to generate same exception on my local system as well as demo server. but it can't reproduce. for reproducing that exception we have tried with increase load on demo server hit the multiple url at time download and upload large files, but still I am not able to reproduce it.
below stack trace of CouldNotLockPageException, after this exception we have to restart the tomcat

stack trace

> [WARN ] 2021-03-24 04:26:56.355 [http-nio-8080-exec-68] PageAccessSynchronizer - Thread 'http-nio-8080-exec-68' failed to acquire lock to page with id '1', attempted for 1 minute out of allowed 1 minute. The thread that holds the lock has name 'http-nio-8080-exec-66'.
> [WARN ] 2021-03-24 04:26:56.357 [http-nio-8080-exec-68] PageAccessSynchronizer - "http-nio-8080-exec-66" daemon prio=5 tid=368 state=BLOCKED
> org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Threads$ThreadDump: null
> at biz.smart360.elastic.app.DefaultAppCache$DefaultUserCache.bizRepository(AppCache.scala:146) ~[elastic-app.jar:?]
> at biz.smart360.biz.repository.BizUserSession.repositoryOperations(BizUserSession.scala:73) ~[smart360.jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
> at biz.smart360.biz.repository.BizRepositoryOperationsDirectResolver.repositoryOperations(BizRepositoryOperationsDirectResolver.scala:21) ~[smart360.jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
> at biz.smart360.biz.repository.BizRepositoryOperationsDirectResolver.openedTabularViewpointsMenu(BizRepositoryOperationsDirectResolver.scala:47) ~[smart360.jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
> at biz.smart360.biz.repository.BizRepositoryOperationsResolverTransientProxyBase.openedTabularViewpointsMenu(BizRepositoryOperationsResolverTransientProxyBase.java:62) ~[smart360.jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
> at biz.smart360.webapp.ui.component.navigation.RepositoryNavigationActionsPanel.onInitialize(RepositoryNavigationActionsPanel.java:101) ~[smart360.jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.apache.wicket.Component.fireInitialize(Component.java:878) ~[wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
> at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.internalInitialize(MarkupContainer.java:1070) ~[wicket-core-7.9.0.jar:7.9.0]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
> ***[ERROR] 2021-03-24 04:26:56.359 [http-nio-8080-exec-68] InMemoryErrorReporting - Error with id 19bbb439-e89f-40ad-89c3-a05a6805e53e registered for user jiwon.lim1@y-k.co.kr:
> org.apache.wicket.page.CouldNotLockPageException: Could not lock page 1. Attempt lasted 1 minute
> at org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer.lockPage(PageAccessSynchronizer.java:167)
> at org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer$2.getPage(PageAccessSynchronizer.java:245)
> at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.getPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:113)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getStoredPage(PageProvider.java:299)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.isNewPageInstance(PageProvider.java:211)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractBookmarkableMapper.checkExpiration(AbstractBookmarkableMapper.java:335)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractBookmarkableMapper.processHybrid(AbstractBookmarkableMapper.java:258)
> at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractBookmarkableMapper.mapRequest(AbstractBookmarkableMapper.java:364)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.CompoundRequestMapper.mapRequest(CompoundRequestMapper.java:147)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.https.HttpsMapper.mapRequest(HttpsMapper.java:101)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.resolveRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:189)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:219)
> at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
> at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)***

Comment: You should check why `DefaultUserCache.bizRepository` doesn't return a result in under a minute.
Why do you 'have to restart tomcat'? Are all your web server threads stuck in calling the 'bizRepository'?

Comment: Same code base is working fine on another servers and there is no such type of exception **" org.apache.wicket.page.CouldNotLockPageException: Could not lock page 1. Attempt lasted 1 minute at "** but I have already checked and trying to create same exception on my local as well as demo server but till I am not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

Wicket throws `CouldNotLockPageException` when an HTTP request cannot get a lock on a page instance for some duration (the default is 1 minute).

In your particular case an HTTP worker thread has acquired a lock on that page instance and waits at:

```
biz.smart360.elastic.app.DefaultAppCache$DefaultUserCache.bizRepository(AppCache.scala:146)
```

For some reason this method takes more than a minute.
You need to debug why it takes so long.

To reproduce it locally you could add `TimeUnit.SECONDS(90).sleep()` at `RepositoryNavigationActionsPanel.onInitialize(RepositoryNavigationActionsPanel.java:101)` and then load the page and click on some Ajax link in it.